# Avoid user pk in Django user edit form

Tags: python, django

I want to create a Django form to edit user information. I have:

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^settings/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/', views.edit_profile, name='edit'),
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def edit_profile(request, pk):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = UserForm(instance=user)
    return render(request, 'edit_user.html', {'form': form})
```

Like this, when a user edit its information can change pk from url and see other users information. How can I hide this pk in the url?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I know that request.user is always the login user

Comment: @P.Rodoreda so, what's the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to accept the pk in the URL at all. The logged in user is always available as `request.user`, so you can pass this directly as the instance argument to the form.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
else:
    form = UserForm(instance=request.user)
return render(request, 'edit_user.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

update your url

*url(r'^settings/', views.edit_profile, name='edit')*

try to send POST request to that **url** and no one see what are you sending to the server.

Answer (score -2):

you can create a custom template filter that check if the user is editing his own profile or not.

create custom tag:

first send context called `pk` that equal the profile pk then..

create a directory called `templatetags` in the app directory and add a python file in it called `__init__.py` -*two under scores*- now create another file called `profile_extras.py` type this in:

```
from django.template.loader_tags import register
@register.filter(name="ownPro")
def ownPro(user, id):
    if Profile.objects.get(id=id).user == user:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

now in the edit profile template add this

```
{% load profile_extras %}

{% if user|ownPro:pk %}

....
allow to edit

{% else %}
    <p>you are not allowed </p>
{% endif %}
```

> don't forget to restart the server